# How to run a clojure uberjar from within a java application?

Tags: java, java-8, clojure, uberjar

I can run smoothly [this clojure uberjar](https://downloads.metabase.com/v0.36.0/metabase.jar) from command line like this:

```
java -jar metabase.jar
```

I tried to do the same from a Java application. With the use of [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) it worked. However, it failed with [URLClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html).

Here is my code and the thrown exception:

```
private void startMetabase() {
    try {
        URL metabaseJarURL = new File("/path/to/metabase.jar").toURI().toURL();
        URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { metabaseJarURL }, this.getClass().getClassLoader());

        Class<?> classToLoad = Class.forName("metabase.core", true, child);

        Method main = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);

        Object[] args = new String[] {};
        main.invoke(null, args);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at clojure.lang.Namespace.<init>(Namespace.java:34)
    at clojure.lang.Namespace.findOrCreate(Namespace.java:176)
    at clojure.lang.Var.internPrivate(Var.java:156)
    at metabase.core.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at my.Poc.startMetabase(KeywordsFinder.java:69)
    at my.Poc.main(KeywordsFinder.java:32)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/core__init.class, clojure/core.clj or clojure/core.cljc on classpath.
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:462)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:424)
    at clojure.lang.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:338)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Any reason why it has to start in the current JVM, rather than just using process builder?

Comment: @Michael I tried the process builder approach and it worked perfectly. I wanted to try an alternate solution.

Comment: Why did you want to try an alternate solution?

Comment: @Michael To better understand JVM inner works.